# calling knockoutjs viewmodel functions

Tags: knockout.js, viewmodel

here the context for better understanding:

i have a datagrid in my main page with a button in each row . when the user click on it it load another page via ajax jquery and popup it inside a bootstrap modal dialog :

```
<script>
var sharedadminID = 0;
var alreadyloaded = 0;
...
    function EditClick(args) {
            var gridObj = $("#DetailsGrid").data("ejGrid");
            var data = gridObj.getSelectedRecords()[0].ID;
            sharedadminID = data;
            $("#prdmodalbody").load("pages/modals/AddEditPRD.html");
}
</script>
```

the AddEditPRD.html page have it's viewmodel defined like so

```
<script>

        var PRDVM = function () {
            ID = ko.observable();
            DESIGNATION = ko.observable();
            PRIX = ko.observable();

            loadproduct = function () {
                alert("innerloadproduct2222");
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "/Admin/GetProduct?i=" + sharedadminID,
                    success: function (html) {

                        ID = html.ID,
                        DESIGNATION = html.DESIGNATION,
                        PRIX = html.PRIX                      
                    },
                    async: false
                });
            }
            loadproduct();
        };

        $(document).ready(function () {

            if (alreadyloaded == 0) {
                VM = new PRDVM();
                ko.applyBindings(VM,        document.getElementById("#prdmodalbody"));
                alreadyloaded = 1;
            }
            else
                VM.loadproduct();
        });

    </script>
```

it work when i click the button for the first time , but not after that .

no error on the console , and it seem that the loadproduct function is not fired 
except for the first time .

any help s welcome

Answer (score 0):

There are a *lot* of problematic points in your code:

- (Over)use of globals;
- Awkward formatting (makes it hard to read and debug, but also hard to help you);
- Synchronous `ajax` calls (*why?* this is very seldom a good idea and can break the whole thing again if you change it to async later on);
- You *overwrite* the observable properties with `ID = html.ID`;
- Syntax errors/problems, using `,` where you intended `;`
- Not exposing the observables at all: how is any bit of code supposed to "see" `ID` and so on if you don't expose them?
- The combination of `alreadyloaded` sortoff serving as a boolean, while it is a number (that is compared with `==` instead of the safer `===`)
- Why are you doing the `if...else` *at all* in the `ready` callback? It should be called once anyhow...

Fix all those issues and very likely you'll find the root cause to your problem.

Comment: the observable are exposed and bound correctly, and they are updated with the ajax call result, the ready function is called each time i click the edit button of the parent page

Comment: anyway my main concern is to know why the loadproduct method is fired only first time . thanks

Comment: No, they're not, the `observable` variables like `ID` in your post are *not* visible outside the view model constructor function instances. [The other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41381810/419956) clearly shows the difference, as that *does* expose them using the `self = this` idiom.

Answer (score 0):

I think this mix of knockout and DOM manipulation is problematic... you could probably do this in a more pure knockout solution.

That being said, I think the problem is how you modify the data... you must update observables by wrapping them in parentheses or knockout won't update the view, although it will do a 'one time' binding with non-observable data. It's  also a good habit to track this with a scoped variable (like self) so you don't get weird scoping issues in different contexts:

```
    var PRDVM = function () { 
        var self = this;
        self.ID = ko.observable();
        self.DESIGNATION = ko.observable();
        self.PRIX = ko.observable();

        self.loadproduct = function () {
            alert("innerloadproduct2222");
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "/Admin/GetProduct?i=" + sharedadminID,
                success: function (html) {

                    self.ID(html.ID);
                    self.DESIGNATION(html.DESIGNATION);
                    self.PRIX(html.PRIX);                      
                },
                async: false
            });
        }
        self.loadproduct();
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {

        if (alreadyloaded == 0) {
            VM = new PRDVM();
            ko.applyBindings(VM,        document.getElementById("#prdmodalbody"));
            alreadyloaded = 1;
        }
        else
            VM.loadproduct();
    });
```